# "unknown" OAuthException when iterating over pagination

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I get this error semi regularly when iterating over pagination of a user's feed (ala https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/feed)

```
{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

If I adjust my limits, sometimes I can get it to work, however, sometimes even adjusting down to 1 doesn't work.  If I adjust the until value, I can sometimes get it to work as well.

It's as if there's corrupt data on facebook's end that I have to force it to skip over.  Is there an appropriate/best practice way to handle this situation?

Because it works for the majority of the user's feed accesses, it seem that it isn't a access token issue, but actually a bug on facebook's side.

Comment: How much are you iterating? Your access_token could expire while going through the data. Have you tried doing other calls using the same access_token after getting this error?

Comment: yes, this is with off line token (yes, I know they will go the way of the dodo, I'll worry about that later) and I am able to move beyond the problematic area.  Also reported as a bug and seems to be accepted that it is a bug as has been triaged.

Basically what I'm doing is iterating over all friends of mine and then iterating over every post from the feed, at some points for some users it throes errors, but I can eventually get to the error point by decreasing my limit to 1 and then if I hit 1 and still get an error I decrease the "until" value by 60*60*24 till it works again (which it does)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a bunch too. I paginate through the feed, and then there are certain times where I get a similar error. Although now it's `code: 2` and adding the `is_transient: true` parameter as well as a `fbtrace_id`.

To solve it, I continually retry, dropping the `until` by 10000 seconds until the request succeeds.